# React Native: Under what circumstances do you have to manually add dependencies of your dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, dependencies

I have the component `react-native-modal-datetime-picker` in my React Native project. It's throwing the following error:

**error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module '@react-native-community/datetimepicker' from 'node_modules/react-native-modal-datetime-picker/src/DateTimePickerModal.android.js: @react-native-community/datetimepicker could not be found within the project.**

It seems that there's a reference in the `react-native-modal-datetime-picker` module to the `@react-native-community/datetimepicker` module. I've never run into a scenario before where I had to manually add a dependency of another dependency. Does anyone have any insight on why this is happening?

Comment: i phase same problem.try to delete your node-modules and package-lock file and npm install

Comment: @PrakashKarena This didn't work for me unfortunately, but manually adding @react-native-community/datetimepicker did work. Why do you think that deleting node_modules and package-lock.json changed anything for you?

Answer (score 6):

[see the github](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker)

you need to run this:

`expo install react-native-modal-datetime-picker @react-native-community/datetimepicker`

Comment: thanks! I'm actually not using Expo, and I was able to resolve it by manually adding @react-native-community/datetimepicker. What you're saying is valid according to the Github link though.

Comment: Omg i was searching for hours thank you bro literraly :!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same problem and I found that the autolinking wasn't done so I had to run the command

```
npx react-native link @react-native-community/datetimepicker
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

‘ @react-native-community/datetimepicker’ is declared as a peer dependency to ‘ react-native-modal-datetime-picker’. Peer dependencies must be installed alongside the original package.

Answer (score -1):

In dependencies, there should be **node** in case node is not there install `npm i node`
and try installing **date picker** again.